# R what's the result of iteration throught a dataframe?

Tags: r, loops

I have trouble to iterate throught a data.Frame.

```
# a is a dataframe, with names 'f','d','sess', ...
for (x in a) 
# find all events BEFORE the event x 
#    ('d' is the beginning of the event in ms, 'e' is the end of it)
a[a$f < as.numeric(x['d']),] -> all_before

x['Epe'] = min( as.numeric(x['d'])-all_before$f)
}
```

It just does not change my original data.frame. Is there a way to change my *a*  dataframe on-the-fly or should I absolutely create a new one and fill it in?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more as to what you want, an explicit `for` loop is often not needed.

Comment: And also please provide example data, this code is rather cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

A dataframe is essentially a list.  Using a dataframe as the input to a for loop does the same thing as when you use a list as the input.

```
> for(x in list(x = 1:3, y = letters, z = lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars))){print(x)}
[1] 1 2 3
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"
[20] "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           hp  
   30.09886     -0.06823
```

It iterates through each element of the list.  In the case of a dataframe that means that it iterates through the columns of the dataframe.

```
> dat <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = rep("this is y", 3))
> dat
  x         y
1 1 this is y
2 2 this is y
3 3 this is y
> for(i in dat){print(i)}
[1] 1 2 3
[1] this is y this is y this is y
Levels: this is y
```

Comment: Thank you... I've find it hard to understand the difference between all the differents kind of data container in R language. I lack in knowledge about the underlying mechanisms of R. Actually, I want to iterate along my dataframe (row by row... for(in) doesn't work in this case I guess), access the row data, and fill a new column of the fly.

Comment: @Loic You can do it with a for loop but you really should be using an `apply` statement instead to do something like that.  As an example - this makes a new column in the mtcars dataframe called "max" and puts the max value in the row into that column: `mtcars$max <- apply(mtcars, 1, max)`